# Increased resource utilization on Azure PostgreSQL replica

Tags: postgresql, azure

I noticed that each 2nd day of a month, my Azure PostgreSQL replica has increased resource utilization. I was looking what's the cause, but couldn't find any. Do you know what might be causing this?

[image: CPU usage]

This chart shows the CPU usage, and each 2nd day of a month I have this peak. I thought it might be a backup but couldn't find any configuration for that. Can anyone direct me when I should start looking to find the cause?

Comment: Is it in the same time too? If you can't find the source then maybe wait for 2nd of October and look in `pg_stat_activity` during peak.

Comment: Thanks, I'll this check on the 2nd of October

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening once a month then I assume that you would have a scheduled job in that day of the month.

Regards,
Oury

Comment: It looks like it, but it's not my scheduled job. I checked them all, that's why I'm curious if the Azure itself does something. I checked the backups, but it's not related to them.

Comment: Could you try to monitor the number of active connections during this peak hour. You can simply check this with the show processlist; command. Let me know if that help.